# Java Opencv Mat constructor mismatch

Tags: java, c++, opencv

I am trying to create a Mat object as follows:

```
// ROI by creating mask for the trapezoid
Mat mask = Mat(frame.rows(), frame.cols(), CvType.CV_8UC1, new Scalar(0));
```

However I get the following compile-time error:

```
The method Mat(int, int, int, Scalar) is undefined for the type
```

Whereas in `Mat.class` file I can surely see the following function signature:

```
//
// C++: Mat::Mat(int rows, int cols, int type, Scalar s)
//

// javadoc: Mat::Mat(rows, cols, type, s)
public Mat(int rows, int cols, int type, Scalar s)
{

    nativeObj = n_Mat(rows, cols, type, s.val[0], s.val[1], s.val[2], s.val[3]);

    return;
}
```

Is this a bug, or?

Comment: shouldn't it be `Mat mask = new Mat(...)` in the first place?

Comment: You are right, stupid of me, I am converting the code from C++ to Java, hence the mistake. I'll accept it as answer if you write it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature is correct.
In Java you need to use the `new` keyword to create new objects:

```
Mat mask = new Mat(frame.rows(), frame.cols(), CvType.CV_8UC1, new Scalar(0));
```